# is auto-refresh is possible in jquery without making the page blink?? like in facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, facebook

I'm having a  problem about the blinking of the page for my auto-refresh of the page function. Is there a way to make my this blinking of the said page begone? 
Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function refreshPage() { location.reload(); }
    $(document).ready(function () {
       setInterval('refreshPage()', 5000);
    });
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can open your page in an `iframe` and then reload that iframe.

Comment: iframe?? how can i achieve that sir...

Comment: Ok, I think i misunderstood your question. If you are trying to add server updates as facebook, then try using some server push technologies like `APE`(http://ape-project.org/)

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to refresh the entire page. E.g. logo, menu would stay, while a content somewhere will refresh. I would mark this content with e.g. a `div`:

```
<div id="content">
    <!-- stuff in here is to be periodically refreshed -->
</div>
```

Then, I would add a server-side URL to create just that refreshable content. This depends of course on your server-side technology, but it is probably trivial. Say this URL is `http://yourserver/path/to/page/content`.

Then with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#content").load("http://yourserver/path/to/page/content");
    }, 5000);
});
```

This is the principle of operation, you may adjust the details. See [$.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/). This will greatly eliminate the blink.

Comment: how about my my redirection sir.. i used ID's to redirect my pages like clientID,WorkerID etc... how can i put it with the http that you send..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, could you elaborate? If you want to reload the current page with URL parameters and all, just use `$("content").load(document.location.href);`